# Custom matcher in jasmine with Typescript

Tags: typescript, jasmine

I am using Typescript and I want to implement custom matchers in jasmine(2.8.0).
When I try to use the example at https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/custom_matcher.html
I get the below error from karma:

```
(96,12): error TS2339: Property 'toBeGoofy' does not exist on type 'Matchers<{ hyuk: string; }>'.
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare the method in an interface, like so:

```
declare namespace jasmine {
  interface Matchers {
    toBeGoofy(expected?: string): boolean;
  }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5456